# How to record right click on cytoscape.js element with selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide, cytoscape.js

I am writing selenium (python) tests for a site that contains a cytoscape.js tree. I am trying to record a ritgh click action on one of the cytoscape's elements (node) but i cannot find a way to do it in python and when i create the test in browser using the selenium IDE is nt recording actions on cytoscape.

Answer (score 0):

To perform a right click in Python, you'll need to use the `context_click` action from `ActionChains`.

```
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
actionChains = ActionChains(driver)

web_element_to_click = driver.find_element_by_id("someId")
actionChains.context_click(web_element_to_click).perform()
```

If you cannot locate a web element to click (due to dynamic browser page), you may need to click by coordinates instead, by moving the mouse to the coordinates then performing `context_click`:

```
# move_by_offset moves your mouse from its last known location to given x,y offset
ActionChains(driver).move_by_offset(x,y).context_click().perform()
```

Comment: find_element_by_id (or xpath e.t.c.) is not working for cytoscape elements. Working with coordinates is not possible at this case. Is there any way for selenium to work with cytoscape?

Comment: We would probably need to see the page source HTML to get a better answer for this. If you add it to your original question, I can take a look.